# Change link color based on href attribute

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors, selector, permalinks

I'm working on Squarespace for a client that needs to add special blog post that are styled different.
The problems is that this template doesn't allow it and the client can't code, so I'm trying to do it with custom CSS in a way that prevents errors.

All this "special" post have a link with href that contains the word "special", so I'm styling them with the css selector:

```
[href*="Special"] { style }.
```

My question is if the client add more special post like "Special landscape", "Special Images", "Special theme" and so on, i can target them with:

```
[href*="Special+l"] { style }. 
[href*="Special+I"] { style1 }.
[href*="Special+t"] { style2 }.
```

Is there a way to style them differently based on the href without needing to know the first letter of the second word?
Otherwise if the client put a different second word the style will not be applied.

I tried with nth-of-type() and so on but since each link are child of different blog's cards it doesn't work.

I hope explain myself :)

Comment: Are there many blog cards, could you target the links through them?

Comment: Currently, any `href` containing the word Special should get the style is that not what you want? `[href*="Special"] { style }` this matched anything containing 'Special' in it's `href`

Comment: There are many blog cards, each one of this cards inside has a link with those href. Each href is correspondent to a category set by the admin panel. My point is that every "special" category start with the word special followed by another word chose by the client that i can't control so if i use `[href*="Special"] { style }` or  `[href*="Special+"] { style }` i still style all of them. I would like to style them all differently.

Comment: Can you use javascript? I don't think CSS can do this.

Comment: can you specify the **differently** ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think OP means that each 'special' link should have a unique colour...?

Comment: I can't use javascript and to style them differently i mean to change color of the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible the way you would have like it.

If you want to have different stylings for these links, for example:

```
<a href="special-boat"></a>   // in blue
<a href="special-car"></a>    // in red
<a href="special-house"></a>  // in green
```

you need to know what is the second word of the link to give it a special styling.
ATM in your case you can have different styling for normal links, links with "special" in the `href-attribute` and links with "special-" plus more words in the `href-attribute`.

If you do not know the second word, all you can do is to prepare stylings for as many cases you can think of.

Another way COULD be, that you give your customer a list of special string combinations which you prepare to have an own styling if he uses them in the link.

```
<a href="you-dont-know-the-link-c0000FF"></a>   // in blue
<a href="you-dont-know-the-link-c00FF00"></a>   // in green
<a href="you-dont-know-the-link-cFF0000"></a>   // in red
```

and in your CSS you have:

```
a[href*=c0000FF] {
  color: blue;
}
a[href*=c00FF00] {
  color: green;
}    a[href*=cFF0000] {
  color: red;
}
```

You can tell him to use these special strings if he wants to have his link in a special color. But this is 1. not really comfortable for him and 2. quite a strange look in the URLs.

---

Edit: and be sure not to use real words or strings that could be used in other links if you don't want them to be colored by mistake.

Comment: and if you want l the links to look different (as long as the 2nd word in the href attribute is different) u should use javascript

Comment: That second approach is clever + 1

Comment: Thanks Nils, i was hoping i didn't know a way to do it. I thought to preparing many cases but i'm aware is definitely not the best practise.  Probably get back with him and discuss for a better solution.

Comment: i would probably use data attribute for color ... not sure it's a good idea to include color in link like this

Comment: @TemaniAfif
Yes, I know that this is not best practice, but I thought this is probably easier for the customer (who does not know anything about HTML). Don't you think?

Comment: no i don't agree :) the idea is good, but not good at all to add something in the link like this. You know that links are the main part of websites and usefull for SEO, and have a meaning ! so adding this may impact badly the SEO. and what if he want to change the color ? he will then break the link which is very bad ... check my answer to see alternative to what you have done but in a good way

Answer (score 1):

you can use `href` attr to select it

```css
a[href*="http://abc.go.com"] {
  color: #db4344;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://abc.go.com/">link 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you accepted the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49068487/8620333), here is another way I think it could be better as am not sure appending color like that inside links is a good idea.

You can rely on CSS variable and do something like this:

```css
a[href*=special] {
  color: var(--c);
}
```

```html
<a href="special-1" style="--c:red">link 1</a>
<a href="special-something" style="--c:blue">link 2</a>  
<a href="special-something-else" style="--c:green">link 2</a>
```

Or you can directly apply inline-style:

```html
<a href="special-1" style="color:red">link 1</a>
<a href="special-something" style="color:blue">link 2</a>  
<a href="special-something-else" style="color:green">link 2</a>
```

Or use data-attribute:

```css
a[data-color="red"] {
 color:red;
}
a[data-color="blue"] {
 color:blue;
}
a[data-color="green"] {
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<a href="special-1" data-color="red">link 1</a>
<a href="special-something" data-color="blue">link 2</a>  
<a href="special-something-else" data-color="green">link 2</a>
```